Load Local WebSite Folder from Document Directory
I am trying to load Website Folder from the Document Directory. It's a PWA Bundle. When i load the Folder from the Bundle, It loads in WkWebview. But when i try to load it from Document Directory, it's not loading from the folder. May files are missing including main.js, though all those files are there in the bundle(i double checked).
Below is the Sample Code which is not loading.
var url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("DownloadedHTMLNew").appendingPathComponent("index.html")
    let readAccessToURL: URL = url.deletingLastPathComponent()
    self.webView?.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: readAccessToURL)

Below is the code which is loading from bundle directory.
if let value = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "DownloadedHTMLNew") {
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: value)
self.webView?.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
}

Ok now i am able to load the bundle but still i am getting several issues like particular js files are not opening. or they are not able to referencing other source files or modules.
Below is the example of the error :
Received an error from JavaScript: Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=133, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: methodLoadModule.get("homepageLoadModuleCall") is not a function. (In 'methodLoadModule.get("homepageLoadModuleCall")(resultValue, cartData)', 'methodLoadModule.get("homepageLoadModuleCall")' is undefined), WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=49, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F52DBF9-9D88-434C-B093-502E22823BB8/Documents/DownloadedHTMLNew/assets/js/main.js, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred})
Let me know your suggestions.

Have you written code to copy the files from the Bundle to the documents directory?

Does the files exist at url? You can check it.

@Paulw11 Yes. I did.

@Larme yes files are existed at the url

Enumerate the contents of folder FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("DownloadedHTMLNew") check that all your JS files are there too.

You should point the url to the parent directory not the index fileURL. You are using the same url for both.

@LeoDabus i have updated the code. if you can check.

@Larme yes i have checked that all my files and pwa bundle is there in the folder.

Create the access url first and pass isDirectory true. Then append the index component and create the fileURL

I guess you are saving this url after downloading the files. Note that your app is sandboxed and you need to create a new url every time you launch your app. Anyway it is just a guess.

Have you tried to use loadFileRequest instead?

@LeoDabus, yes App is sandboxed. and everytime when app launches i got the diff url as per the application id. (var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F52DBF9-9D88-434C-B093-502E22823BB8/Documents/DownloadedHTMLNew/. like this. )

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
